# react native expo webview crash application when open pdf uri android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

Try to preview a file(pdf,word,doc),once select from document picker?
using webview, but it crash the application in android

How to read and preview file uri from document picker?
<WebView
source={{
uri: "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FHalo-6108c6f8-a72d/DocumentPicker/test.pdf"
}}

Comment: Did you found any solution?